# How to dismiss contextual menu of UIWebView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an iPad app where a `UIWebView` is loading a html page which consists of n number of phone numbers within a href tag.
And  on tap of these phone numbers iOS default `contextual` menu like a popover-controller is  getting displayed with 3 default options like --- Send Message, Add to Contacts and Copy.

At certain point of time I’m just popping all the `UIViewController` to `rootViewController`, so when this action is getting performed if this `contextual` menu is displayed on screen then it is not at all getting dismissed even when the view comes to `rootViewController` from the view which consists the `UIWebView` with phone numbers. I guess this is because the `contextual` menu is getting displayed from `UIWindow`(like `UIAlertView`).

I want to dismiss or hide this `contextual` menu at this point programmatically.

I have tried to achieve this by below attempts,

1)  On `viewDidDisappear`,

```
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
```

2)I tried by fast enumeration like below,

```
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews){
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIPopoverController class]]) {
            [(UIPopoverController *)subViews dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
//similiarly I tried by checking for UIMenuController as well
```

None of the above attempts was successful in achieving this.
Can any one let me know how can I dismiss `contextual` menu of `UIWebView` programmatically?

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before popping to the root view controller you can use

Objective-C:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Swift:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

to get rid of the contextual menu.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this as well didn't worked for me :-( My problem is before popping out the view controllers, contextual menu is already in screen, and on viewWillDisappear even after dismissing current view controller or popping to rootview controller, the pop up which was on screen still exists on screen, since it is added to window from iOS I guess like UIAlertViews

Comment: I managed to recreate your problem and fixed it by putting this in the view controller containing the web view. The whole action of popping to root is then

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Are you sure you dismissed the view controller in the right place?

Comment: yup I did it in the same way still of no luck :(

Comment: Could you share the code you use to pop all the view controllers to the root?

Comment: looping all the preset view controllers and calling dismissViewControllerAnimated api